# Magnific Popup content appendto/inside another DIV

Tags: jquery, callback, magnific-popup, appendto

I would like to load the content of .mfp-wrap inside another DIV. I'm trying to do that with callbacks wihtout luck.

Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried already? You might get more help with more contextual information, examples and demonstrating you've tried "something"

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information it's incredibly hard to understand what you're trying to do here. It sounds like you want the content of one div to appear in another? Surely you could just use:

```
$('#anotherDiv').html($('.mfp-wrap').html());
```

Comment: Yes, you're right @joey-emery. I regret not having been more specific. 

I have a basic site structure: An aside on the left and a main container floating to the right. What I'm trying to make is that the Magnific Popup load on the main container, so that the aside is always visible.

Thanx!